# Var depending functions in vb.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, function

(I am a ASP.NET programmer that uses mostly VB but can also program in C#)

I like to have a list(t) full with keywords and function names.
For example:

```
Dim MyList as new List(of MyFunctions)
MyList.add(new Myfunction("descr","DBGetDescription()"))
MyList.add(new Myfunction("Name","DBGetName()"))
MyList.add(new Myfunction("create","DBGetCreateTS()"))

Public Class Myfunctions
  Public code     as String
  Public function as String
  Public Sub new(in_code as String, in_function as String)
    code = in_code
    function = in_function
  End Sub
End Class

'what do i want to search for:
Dim ToDo as String = "descr"
'search for it
Dim ThisFunction as MyFunction = MyList.find(function(x) x.code = ToDo)
'answer in 'thisfunction' gives me the name of the function i need to use
Dim FunctionIWantToUse = ThisFunction.function
```

(the DBGetDescription, DBGetName and DBGetCreateTS are existing routines)
I know the name of the function(routine) I want to start but it is inside a variable.
Is it possible in VB (or in C#) to start the function?
Is there a work around?

M.

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you saying that you need to find a class's method by name, or that you need to find a delegate in a list by name, or you need to dynamically execute code that is stored in a string (i.e. the commands in the body of the function are in the string)?

Comment: Yes. **Reflection**. Get that method and Invoke()  it.

Comment: @Adriano Repetti: Thank you for quick reply. I will look in to it.

Comment: My question is downvoted by somebody. I like to know by who and why. Was my question that stupid?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `delegate` which is basically a reference to a function. This allows you to map "names" to actual functions, to make it possible to call a function from a string name.

```
Delegate Function MyDelegateType() as string

Sub Main
    ' Create a dictionary mapping string names to the corresponding function.'
    ' Ive used a dictionary in my sample code, as its more straightforward, '
    ' but it would be trivial to wrap the name/function tuple up in a class and use a list'
    Dim MyList as new Dictionary(of string, MyDelegateType)
    MyList.Add("descr", addressof DBGetDescription)
    MyList.add("Name", addressof DBGetName)
    MyList.add("create", addressof DBGetCreateTS)

    ' Get the function for a key, and call it.'        
    Console.WriteLine(MyList.Item("descr")())
End Sub

Function DBGetDescription() as string
    return "MyDescription"
End Function
Function DBGetName() as string
    return "MyName"
End Function
Function DBGetCreateTS() as string
    return "MyCreateTS"
End Function
```

Comment: It is not necessary to create your own delegate.  There are already built in `Action` and `Func` delegates available:  `Dim MyList As New Dictionary(Of String, Func(Of String))`

Comment: Its also It is not necessary to use a Func instead of a Delegate, the latter has advantages.

Comment: IN my example i told that 1 had 3 functions ready. That the answer is, with delegate, is because i asked for it in my question.